# Multiple read from same stream throwing Stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

Tags: c#, .net, stream, download

I am downloading files.For that I divided file into segments.

Each segment concurrently accessing the same Input Stream.
So the error `Stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations` occurs in Stream.Read() Method.

My code is

```
Stream InputStream = response.GetResponseStream(); //where response is HttpWebResponse
//Following Read is called for each segment
InputStream.Read(buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
```

My Question is how to read from multiple thread at same time.It should be possible as many downloaders has concurrent segment download facility.Also let me know if I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to allow single thread to read at a time.

```
Stream InputStream = null;

lock(InputStream)
{
  InputStream = response.GetResponseStream(); //where response is HttpWebResponse
  //Following Read is called for each segment
  InputStream.Read(buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
}
```

> The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by
>   obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a
>   statement, and then releasing the lock. The following example includes
>   a lock statement, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Comment: Then the advantage of downloading over multiple segment is lost,isn't it?

Comment: It wont be lost, lock will allow the threads to queue up and will allow the queued thread to access the code segment as soon as one thread leaves the lock.